# How to clean my scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

```
> sfdx force:source:push
```

Using push command I'm pushing all my custom created object into Salesforce, even though the object fields are present already in my scratch org. But I need to clean or delete the present object fields and reuse the org! Any Idea to reuse a scratch org?

Answer (score 9):

Scratch orgs are intended to be throw-away and have a limited life span of at most 30 days. Instead of trying to re-use a scratch org you should throw it away and build a new one.